# Backup Esxi server installed on a pendrive

Tags: backup, usb-flash-drive, esxi

I've installed and configured an Esxi server that starts from a usb pendrive.
I would like to prepare a perfect clone of it and tape it in my server for the sad day when the 1st one will die.
A brutal total copy of files will work or I should choose another procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the OS you're making the backup with. If you can find a windows box, [usbimagewriter for windows](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer) has worked pretty well in most cases, its a one click application to copy an image of a USB, and pop it back into the USB.

Comment: Any kind of solution is welcome for any os!
The easier the better :) Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

We have a couple of HP Microservers that boot Alpine Linux off USB sticks and having tried DD to make copies (took ages - gave up), I settled for CloneZilla (on a [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=start) live CD) as it was quicker and also gave me backup files I could burn onto a CD and put in a fire safe as an added precaution.

You have to first do a partition backup of the USB stick to a disk drive and then restore it to the target one, but it's pretty quick (I'm using 2GB sticks).

Comment: Clonezilla is ALWAYS the answer! :D

I'll keep you posted... For now: thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. When I was setting up the servers I looked around for a simple, one-click USB stick -> USB stick copy program but didn't come up with anything that 'just worked' - let me know if you find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I just created 27 clones (2 complete IBM BladeCenters) of ESXi 4.1 using [this tool.](http://www.alexpage.de/usb-image-tool/download/)
It took the time it would have taken to manually install 2 or 3 Blades...

The Tool allows you to restore the same image on several usb-sticks simultaneously.